# Solving an 8th order polynomial in terms of unknown variables

Tags: polynomials, math-software

This may be far fetched, but I have an 8th order polynomial which I would like to solve. The polynomial is expressed in terms of variables: $A, B, C, D$. From the context of the problem I know that the variables are greater than 0 and there are two real solutions and then the other 6 solutions are complex.

Is there a way to solve (using computer software) such a polynomial? For reference this is the polynomial I am referring to:
$$
f(x)=Ax^8-2Dx^6+(Bx-Cx^3)^2
$$

From a comment, it would work to let $f(x)=g(x^2)$, where $g(x)=Ax^4−2^3+(−)^2$. How can this, now fourth order, polynomial be solved.

Comment: $f(x)=g(x^2)$ where $g(x)=Ax^4-2Dx^3+x(B-Cx)^2$ and so $x=0$ is a double root of $f$.

Comment: There is no square root involved in the correct expression for g. Anyway you can reduce the degree of g in the search for nonzero roots by dividing by x. What does the resulting cubic actually look like? It seems like it is basically a completely general  cubic, so for an analytical expression you are stuck with the cubic formula.

Comment: You can solve the resulting cubic [this way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#General_cubic_formula), for a symbolic solution. If you are going to be needing numeric values for concrete inputs for $A,B,C,D$, do not use those formulas. Instead use either [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) or [Aberth method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aberth_method).

Comment: The formula for a cubic is already complicated , but in terms of $A,B,C,D$ , it will get even more complicated. Surely, you should use numerical methods, Newton's method usually works , if your start value is close enough.

Answer (score 1):

It is not bad since, expanding, you have
$$f(x)= A x^2 \Big[\frac{B^2}{A}-\frac{2 B C }{A}x^2+\frac{ C^2-2 D}{A}x^4+x^6 \Big]$$ Let
$$x^2=y \qquad a=\frac{ C^2-2 D}{A}\qquad b=-\frac{2 B C }{A}\qquad c=\frac{B^2}{A}$$ and you need to solve the cubic
$$y^3+a y^2+b y+c=0$$

Follow the steps given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#General_cubic_formula) and use, depending of the sign of $\Delta$, either the trigonometric or the hyperbolic method. This will give much nicer looking formula than Cardano method.